# Generate socket junctions for 3D model / Draw cylinders along edges

Tags: vector, 3d, processing, 3d-modelling

I have this Processing sketch in which I'm trying to load a model (.stl or .obj) and build parametric socket junctions for every edge intersection. These will be 3D printed and rods of the appropriate gauge will slot in their holes.

I've been able to draw Spheres at the vertices (in **red**,on the model), but I can't generate the **green** sockets or even the rods in **pink**:
[image: Low Poly Whale - How do I build the green sockets and the pink rods?]

I can get the coordinates of the model's edges:

```
id: 0 0 {-25.805634,-23.170607,13.6315975} -> 1 {-16.868328,-10.148323,6.785455} f: 2
id: 1 1 {-16.868328,-10.148323,6.785455} -> 2 {-52.833824,-10.148322,16.799314} f: 2
....
```

and with these I could draw a `Line3D(Vec3D a, Vec3D b)` ([toxi.geom.Line3D](http://toxiclibs.org/docs/core/toxi/geom/Line3D.html))

But I don't want a Line3D, I need to draw a cylinder between them, thereby getting the rods. To sort of extrude or inflate the line to a 3D volume, if you will...

```
WETriangleMesh whale, redmesh;
```

[bla bla bla]
Then inside `void setup()`:

```
for(WingedEdge e : whale.edges.values()) {
    edges.add(e);
    drawSocket(e);
}

void drawSocket(WingedEdge e) {
    // draw size 2 balls at model vertices
    Sphere ball = new Sphere(e.a, 2);
    // convert to mesh at resolution 6 and add to redmesh
    ball.toMesh(redmesh, 6);
}
```

Then inside `void draw()`:

```
// draw the mesh with the whale
gfx.mesh(whale);
// color the next mesh red
fill(255,0,0);
// draw the mesh with the spheres
gfx.mesh(redmesh);
```

I have found no 3D shape class that can be constructed *in place* from the `Vec3D a, Vec3D b` arguments. Perhaps creating a class to make use of those two coordinates?

If building a shape *in place* is too difficult, maybe a transform then? `pushMatrix()` `translate()` and `popMatrix()`?

**EDIT:** Solved, see below. Thanks!

[image: Low Poly Whale - Rod-and-socketed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to translate the sockets to one vertex in the edge and have them face the opposite vertex. Here's a Processing function that'll take a WETriangleMesh like your whale and return back meshes for the points, sockets and rods. I've written a more complete example [here](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/171284).

```
float socketLength = 30;
float socketRadius = 6;
float rodRadius = 5;
float pointRadius = 10.0;
int resolution = 10;

WETriangleMesh[] convertMeshToRodSockets(WETriangleMesh inMesh) {
  WETriangleMesh[] meshes = new WETriangleMesh[3];

  meshes[0] = new WETriangleMesh();
  meshes[1] = new WETriangleMesh();
  meshes[2] = new WETriangleMesh();

  for (Vertex vert : inMesh.getVertices ()) {
    //Sphere points
    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(vert, pointRadius);
    WETriangleMesh sphereMesh = new WETriangleMesh();
    sphere.toMesh(sphereMesh, resolution);
    meshes[2].addMesh((WETriangleMesh)sphereMesh);
  }

  for (WingedEdge edge : inMesh.edges.values ()) {
    Vec3D pointA = edge.a;
    Vec3D pointB = edge.b;

    //Meshes to store socket shapes
    ZAxisCylinder socket;
    ZAxisCylinder rod;
    WETriangleMesh socketAMesh = new WETriangleMesh();
    WETriangleMesh socketBMesh = new WETriangleMesh();
    WETriangleMesh rodMesh = new WETriangleMesh();

    float distanceBetweenPoints = pointA.distanceTo(pointB);

    //Create sockets and point towards target
    socket = new ZAxisCylinder(new Vec3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), socketRadius, socketLength);
    socket.toMesh(socketAMesh, resolution, 0.0);
    socketAMesh.pointTowards(pointB.sub(pointA));

    //Translate socket to start from the center of the point
    socketAMesh.translate( offsetTranslation(pointA, pointB, socketLength ));

    //Create second socket and look in the opposite direction to face the start point
    socket.toMesh(socketBMesh, resolution, 0.0);
    socketBMesh.pointTowards(pointA.sub(pointB));
    socketBMesh.translate( offsetTranslation(pointB, pointA, socketLength ));

    //Create rod with a length matching the distance between the two points
    rod = new ZAxisCylinder(new Vec3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rodRadius, distanceBetweenPoints);
    rod.toMesh(rodMesh, resolution, 0.0);
    rodMesh.pointTowards(pointB.sub(pointA));

    //Translate the rod to the midpoint of both points
    rodMesh.translate(pointA.add(pointB).scale(0.5));

    //Combine meshes together
    meshes[0].addMesh((WETriangleMesh)rodMesh);
    meshes[1].addMesh((WETriangleMesh)socketAMesh);
    meshes[1].addMesh((WETriangleMesh)socketBMesh);
  }

  return meshes;
}

//Function to return a vector that is slightly offset by a length.
Vec3D offsetTranslation(Vec3D a, Vec3D b, float l) {
  return a.interpolateTo(b, (l*0.5 / a.distanceTo(b)) );
}
```